# Parent class properties are null in child class in php

Tags: php

I have two classes in PHP when I inherit one class from another the properties of parent class are available in child class but their value is null.

Parent Class:

```
    <?php
class Parent_class {
  public $foo;
  public $bar;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->foo = 'This is foo';
    $this->bar = new self();
  }

  public function getFoo(){
    echo 'Foo is: ' .$this->foo;
  }

  public function getBar(){
    echo 'Bar is :' .$this->bar;
  }
}
```

Child Class :

```
<?php
    require './class1.php';
    class Child_class extends Parent_class{
      public function __construct(){
        echo $this->foo;
        print_r($this->bar);
        var_dump(get_object_vars($this));
      }
    }

    $child = new Child_class();
    $child->getFoo();
    $child->getBar();
```

Result :

```
 array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  NULL
  ["bar"]=>
  NULL
}

Foo is: Bar is :
```

So, How can I get those value in child class to. Did I made something wrong here?

Comment: You've overriden the parent constructor. If you want it to run, you need to add `parent::__construct()` to call the parent constuct.

Comment: using `parent::__construct` I get this error `type 1 -- Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) -- at line 7`
and hang my device too. I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: Then you've done something silly somewhere. :P

Comment: `$this->bar = new self();`<-- you've created an infinite loop.

Comment: You are right. but how that makes an infinite loop.  I just created an object of that class only.

Comment: So when you do `new Child_class` the `Child_class`'s `__construct` is run, which calls the parent's `__construct`. Inside that parent `__construct`, you have `new self`, which is the same as `new Parent_class`, so Parent_class `__construct` is called, which runs `new self` which runs the same `__construct` again, which creates a new instance, which runs `new self` again, etc etc forever.

Comment: Ummm. Never thought about that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually override you parent constructor. Try this

```
  public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    echo $this->foo;
    print_r($this->bar);
}
```

Or better if you will output your data via some method, not constructor.